# How can I change the image on my TabControl's TabItem headers when the tab is selected?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the following `TabControl` in a window, and I need the images to change to "awb-white.png" and "center-weighted-white.png", respectively, when those tabs are selected.  (And back to -white when they're not selected).  What's the best way to go about this?  Can it be done in XAML?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication6.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Image Source="images/awb-black.png" Stretch="None" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <Image Source="images/center-weighted-black.png" Stretch="None" />
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Window>
```

I'm brand new to WPF so details will help a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Style` with a default setter for the header, add a `Trigger` on `IsSelected` and created another setter for the new header.

```
<TabItem>
    <TabItem.Style>
         <Style TargetType="TabItem">
              <Setter Property="Header">
                  <Setter.Value>
                      <Image ...>
                  </Setter.Value>
              </Setter>
              <Style.Triggers>
                  <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                      <Setter Property="Header">
                          <Setter.Value>
                              <Image ...>
                          </Setter.Value>
                      </Setter>
                  </Trigger>
              </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
    </TabItem.Style>
</TabItem>
```

As this is rather verbose you might want to inherit from `TabItem` and put that in the default [template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx#styling_controltemplates) where the `Image.Sources` are [bound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to two custom properties, then you just need to set those on your instances.

Also note that the fact that the default value is in a setter is important due to [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), if you set it directly the trigger will not override that value.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail?  I've been trying things like that but haven't gotten anything to work.  I'm completely new to WPF.

Comment: @DaxFohl: Added an example. ([More on styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx))

Comment: Great that works!  Is there any way to reduce the duplication there if I'm going to have a lot of tabs and the .png file name pattern is always the same?

Comment: Ha, must have gotten too excited by the code and didn't even make it to the footnote.  Makes sense though; I'm pretty sure I can figure out the inheritance stuff from your suggestions.

Comment: @DaxFohl: If you have trouble after all i could give a concrete example as well.